# Considering Space Character as Empty Field for PivotTable

Tags: excel, count, pivot-table, string, vba

I'm dynamically creating a PivotTable using VBA.  I would like to count the number of non-zero entries from my source data, but instead of blank cells, my source data have space characters (" ").

I think what happens is that the PivotTable recognizes these spaces as non-blank cells, counting them as non-zero entries.  The result is that the count returns the total number of entries in my source data.  Does anyone know how to avoid this?

My solution was to create a dummy column with a `1` in a row corresponding to a non-zero entry and a `0` in a row corresponding to an entry with a space character in it.  I could then sum my dummy column to get the count of non-zero entries.  The problem with this is that my source dataset is large, so the computation time is too long.

I was hoping that maybe there was some way to tell the PivotTable to treat the space character as a blank field.  I wish I could change the spaces to empty strings, but this takes an enormously long amount of time to do by brute force and I can't get the dataset in another format (the spaces will always be there unless I painstakingly wait for Find/Replace to replace all of them).

Can anyone think of a solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way I can squeeze this into a comment!:

Assuming data of the kind shown in ColumnsA:B (where B2, B4, B6:B8 and B10 are populated with spaces) then a PT *might* look somewhat like shown in ColumnsD:E. ColumnF is an extra column from adding to the Σ VALUES "Count of B" (where being the second instance there a `2` is added automatically).

In the image it is not clear, but here the field is summarized by "Count of Numbers" rather than by "Count":

[image: SO25048037 example]

This may be nothing like what is required but I'm hoping may at least help towards a solution.